# Excluding specific integer from java method return

Tags: java

I'm just starting java, and have written a simple program for returning factors of input numbers. There are two classes, a tester and a the one you see below.

Unfortunately, my output, say if I input 150, is 2, 3, 0, 5, 5.

I know why this is happening; when the local variable q = i, we obviously get 2, 3, 5, 5, but when the conditional in the first if statement is not met, q is read as 0.

Is there a way to exclude a specific integer, in this case 0, from the output? I've struggled with what should be an easy problem for hours, so obviously I'm not seeing something.

I realize there are easier ways to write this program, but all methods must remain as is...

```
public class FactorGenerator {

    private int y;
    private int i;


    public FactorGenerator(int numberToFactor)
    {
        y = numberToFactor;
        i = 2;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreFactors()
    {
        if (i <= y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int nextFactor()
    {

        int q=0;

        if( y % i != 0)
            i++;

        if( y % i == 0)
            {
                y = y / i;
                q = i;
            }           
        return q;
    }   
}
```

Comment: how are you using these methods exactly?

Comment: You don't have to exclude a specific integer. Just tweak your implementation to something which does not require you to do that. Further more, what is the expected output? All factors of 150? 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 30, 50, 150?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix. You need a while loop (to skip all factors that does not clearly divide your y) in here:

```
if( y % i != 0)
        i++;
```

Like this:

```
while( y % i != 0){
        i++;
}
```

Comment: This has helped me understand the difference between a while loop and a for loop, tremendously! It finally clicked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@MicD has suggested correct answer

Another way:

As you have problem with zero, so just check q is not equal to zero

```
    int nextFactor()
{

    int q=0;

    if( y % i != 0)
        i++;

    if( y % i == 0)
        {
            y = y / i;
            q = i;
        }
    if(q!=0)
        return q;
    else
        nextFactor();
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the compiler spits an error when the scope of return q is limited, in this case inside an if statement.